# SSL with old python version (2.7.3) on FreeBSD

Tags: python, python-2.7, openssl, setuptools, freebsd

I installed an old version of Python (2.7.3) from source into a directory (not as the system's default python) to be able to occasionally run an old application. I'd like to configure this environment with pip or easy_install, this doesn't work though as SSL is required and I can't build this version with ssl. The build works but I get the message

```
Failed to build these modules:
_ctypes            _hashlib           _ssl
```

OpenSSL is installed (it's a FreeBSD machine). Building Python 2.7.15 from source works and these modules get installed.

My guess is that 2.7.3 might need an older version of OpenSSL (I have 1.1.1a-freebsd installed).

How can I build this Python version with SSL enabled? (I managed to install setuptools but I cannot use them without SSL)

Comment: Have you tried installing the libssl-dev? I remember having the same issue with Linux Mint way back.

Comment: My server runs on FreeBSD and I have openssl installed and successfully running with my other Python installations (there is no libssl-dev on BSD).

Comment: You probably need to examine the build.log to find out why you couldn't build the openssl module.

Comment: OK, although I didn't find such a file, I created one while running make, including the errors (`make 2>&1 | tee build.log`). So, some protocols needed in this Python version (like SSLv3) are marked as deprecated in the installed openssl version. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: In the meantime, I tried to build an older version of openssl (0.9.8) just for this Python version, but I couldn't compile it with clang. Mixing gcc-compiled openssl with clang-compiled Python doesn't seem to be a very good idea. Maybe I should try to compile both with gcc.

Answer (score 1):

Patches for Python 2.7 to build with newer OpenSSL:

```
--- Modules/_ssl.c.orig 2018-03-05 01:25:37.803984781 +0300
+++ Modules/_ssl.c  2018-03-05 01:25:04.499198913 +0300
@@ -300,8 +300,10 @@
     PySSL_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS
     if (proto_version == PY_SSL_VERSION_TLS1)
         self->ctx = SSL_CTX_new(TLSv1_method()); /* Set up context */
+#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_SSL3
     else if (proto_version == PY_SSL_VERSION_SSL3)
         self->ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv3_method()); /* Set up context */
+#endif
 #ifndef OPENSSL_NO_SSL2
     else if (proto_version == PY_SSL_VERSION_SSL2)
         self->ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv2_method()); /* Set up context */

--- Lib/ssl.py.orig 2017-09-19 10:32:02.000000000 +0300
+++ Lib/ssl.py  2018-03-05 01:38:26.358119752 +0300
@@ -91,14 +91,13 @@
     SSL_ERROR_INVALID_ERROR_CODE,
     )
 from _ssl import HAS_SNI, HAS_ECDH, HAS_NPN
-from _ssl import (PROTOCOL_SSLv3, PROTOCOL_SSLv23,
+from _ssl import (PROTOCOL_SSLv23,
                   PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
 from _ssl import _OPENSSL_API_VERSION

 _PROTOCOL_NAMES = {
     PROTOCOL_TLSv1: "TLSv1",
     PROTOCOL_SSLv23: "SSLv23",
-    PROTOCOL_SSLv3: "SSLv3",
 }
 try:
     from _ssl import PROTOCOL_SSLv2
@@ -664,7 +663,7 @@
     d = pem_cert_string.strip()[len(PEM_HEADER):-len(PEM_FOOTER)]
     return base64.decodebytes(d.encode('ASCII', 'strict'))

-def get_server_certificate(addr, ssl_version=PROTOCOL_SSLv3, ca_certs=None):
+def get_server_certificate(addr, ssl_version=PROTOCOL_TLSv1, ca_certs=None):
     """Retrieve the certificate from the server at the specified address,
     and return it as a PEM-encoded string.
     If 'ca_certs' is specified, validate the server cert against it.
```

I compiled Python 2.7.10 with OpenSSL 1.1.0j under Debian 9.

Comment: Didn't work for me unfortunately. I guess Python 2.7.3 and OpenSSL 1.1.1 are farther away from each other than 2.7.10 and 1.1.0. Still got 10 errors and 10 warnings, like `Modules/_ssl.c:629:26: error: incomplete definition of type 'struct X509_name_entry_st' rdn_level = entry->set;` or `Modules/_hashopenssl.c:163:16: error: variable has incomplete type 'EVP_MD_CTX' (aka 'struct evp_md_ctx_st') EVP_MD_CTX temp_ctx;`

Answer (score 0):

Both python27 and python36 can be installed from the ports and packages (see below incl. the dependencies). I think the problem comes from mixing pip with freebsd ports and packages. Try clean installation and "pkg install python27 python36".

```
# pkg info | grep python
py27-asn1crypto-0.22.0         ASN.1 library with a focus on performance and a 
pythonic API
py27-requests-toolbelt-0.8.0   Utility belt for advanced users of python-requests
py36-asn1crypto-0.22.0         ASN.1 library with a focus on performance and a 
pythonic API
py36-requests-toolbelt-0.8.0   Utility belt for advanced users of python-requests
python27-2.7.16                Interpreted object-oriented programming language
python36-3.6.8_1               Interpreted object-oriented programming language

# pkg info -dx python27
python27-2.7.16:
    openssl-1.0.2r,1
    readline-7.0.5
    libffi-3.2.1_3
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. But I didn't mix ports with packages, and it's not about the system-wide Python which is 2.7.15 (which I installed from packages) in my case and which works fine. It's about one of several separate Python installations built from source. I had no problem building 2.3.6, 2.4.3 and 2.7.15 but I ran into this SSL problems with 2.7.3.